# odoo11 :: wkhtmltopdf is not recognising css

Tags: odoo-11

I have installed wkhtmltopdf however the styling is not working.

I using a mac with OSX 10.13.2 and wkhtmltopdf version is 0.12.1.

I have tried 0.12.4 & restarted odoo. However, it never worked. Is there any special configurations that needs to be done ?

Comment: Check [if the solution here works for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47055149/why-my-pdf-report-is-not-taking-the-css-styles-well-in-odoo)

Comment: I already have all the three configurations .Still its not working. Am logging in as admin.

Comment: The wkhtmltopdf version has to be "qt patched". There are some [new version here](https://builds.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12.1.3/) which works, but I do not see any package for Mac